# Unity3D: Get Velocity after collision

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics, collision, velocity

I'm making a billiard game and I have two questions:

How do I find the velocity of two balls when they collide with each other and how do I apply it to both balls ?

I already know the angles that they're gonna move, I just need to find the velocity that they'll move in those directions.

I was never good at physics/physics programming so I would appreciate any help given! Btw, my game is in 3D.

Thank you for your time!

Edit: What I'm trying to do is make the movement direction match the direction that I'm calculating using this script:

```
if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, Mathf.Infinity, lmm))
{
    location = new Vector3(hit.point.x, 1.64516f, hit.point.z);
}

if (Physics.SphereCast(transform.position, 0.77f, location - transform.position, out hitz, Mathf.Infinity, lmm2))
{
    if (hitz.collider.tag == "Ball")
    {
        Vector3 start = hitz.point;
        end = start + (-hitz.normal * 4);
        lineRenderer2.SetPosition(1, end);
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you considering friction, inelastic collisions, angular momentum and angular velocity in 3d? I think you really should look into kinematics, i think you'd love it. If you wanna take the easy path, just use this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision

Comment: Hi, is there a reason why you want to control the physics by code instead of relying on Unity native physics? That would help me understand the context: basically are you working with rigid bodies set as kinematic?

Comment: I'm using them because unity's really buggy when it comes to this kind of work, for me at least. I've been using the native Unity physics until now but I decided to change to avoid bugs, but that's not the only reason. I want the game to be multiplayer based, so I wanna use RPC calls(update movement) only when balls collide with each other instead of updating it every single frame.

Comment: Also, I tried sending a single rpc call to update the cue ball direction and power but the results weren't the same in other clients(which is super weird).

Comment: U should calculate physics only on server, and update clients with just interpolated position, that is how results will be all the time the same.

Comment: What values should I update to the clients(position, velocity, angularvelocity ?) , and do I do it each frame or only when balls collide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the new velocities by applying an impulse to each ball. We can apply Newton's Third law to do so. PseudoCode:

```
    RelativeVelocity = ball1.velocity - ball2.velocity;
    Normal = ball1.position - ball2.position;
    float dot = relativeVelocity*Normal;
    dot*= ball1.mass + ball2.mass;
    Normal*=dot;
    ball1.velocity += Normal/ball1.mass;
    ball2.velocity -= Normal/ball2.mass;
```

This however does not take into account friction between the two balls nor their angular momentum.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer! Do you think that I should first stop their movement then apply the new velocities ? Else I think it will just multiply their velocity as Unity's native system already adds velocity when they collide with each other.

Comment: Sorry I forgot you were using unity. What exactly does unity do on contact. Is it stopping their penetration? I'm pretty sure the unity physics would be able to simulate this if you keep the restitution low enough.

Comment: Well, on contact I think it changes both their velocity and angular velocity. I'll test your method as soon as I get home, I'm currently away. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, just got the chance to test your code. Unfortunately, it gives me the same results that the native unity's physics system does, which is really weird. The direction differs from the one that I get when I predict the trajectory, I'll add the script to it in the main post.

Comment: Do the collisions LOOK incorrect? Maybe your prediction is wrong. This code and unity act the same because this is what newton predicts, an equal opposite force. I am not very familiar with the way unity works, I'm afraid I can't help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you are trying to do is to apply the speed of "Ball A" as a force to "Ball B", and vice versa as well. If that is the case I would suggest something like this:

Attach this script to all the balls:

```
public class BallCollisionScript : MonoBehaviour 
{   
    public Rigidbody Rigid_Body;

    void Start()
    {
        Rigid_Body = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) 
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag.Equals("Ball"))
        {
            BallScript otherBall = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<BallScript>();
            Rigid_Body.AddForce(otherBall.Rigid_Body.velocity);
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure that all balls are tagged with "Ball".

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer! Do you think that I should first stop their movement then apply the new velocities ? Else I think it will just multiply their velocity as Unity's native system already adds velocity when they collide with each other. (Copy pasted from the new answer)

Comment: You are right. Unity already do that for you (I forgot about that for some reason). Anyway, you could try both ways, by stoping them first and then apply the velocities or just apply their velocities, and see what happens. Althouth I think that stopong them would be the right approach.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your time and sorry for the delayed response, I tried stopping them but I end up getting the same results. Do you have any other idea on how i can fix this issue ? Btw, question got updated. Thanks!